# Turning the same column from 3 rows into 3 columns in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three tables, table a, table b, and table c. Table b combines id's from the other two tables to define a 1-to-(1 to 3) relationship between a and c. So any a will have between 0 and 3 c's.

Performing joins and multiple selects to do validation on objects based on these relationships is too costly. I am trying to get rid of table b altogether, and define the relationships, in order of c.id, in table a.

What is the update query I'm supposed to run? I tried this:

```
UPDATE a SET c_a = (SELECT c_id from b WHERE a_id = a.id LIMIT 0,1 ORDER BY c_id asc);
UPDATE a SET c_b = (SELECT c_id from b WHERE a_id = a.id LIMIT 1,1 ORDER BY c_id asc);
UPDATE a SET c_c = (SELECT c_id from b WHERE a_id = a.id LIMIT 2,1 ORDER BY c_id asc);
```

but that failed, because you cannot use LIMIT in a subquery in MySQL.

How do you do this in SQL?

Comment: In entry-level SQL-92 you can use foreign keys plus a sequence column plus a `CHECK` constraint to effectively enforce the "between 0 and three" rule. However, MySQL does not actually check `CHECK` constraints (other than to parse them -- big deal!) so all bets are off. Have you considered PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you don't mind the order:

```
UPDATE a a, b b
   SET a.c_a = b.c_id
 WHERE a.id = b.a_id

UPDATE a a, b b
   SET a.c_b = b.c_id
 WHERE a.id = b.a_id
   and a.c_a <> b.c_id

UPDATE a a, b b
   SET a.c_c = b.c_id
 WHERE a.id = b.a_id
   and a.c_a <> b.c_id
   and a.c_b <> b.c_id
```

Comment: C_a, c_b, and c_c are all columns in the a table.  Are you sure this is right?  There are one to three rows with a c_id value on the b table, mapping a's to c's - those three relationships are what c_a, c_b, and c_c are supposed to represent - the *c*ategories for the entries in the A table.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but if I do just change a.c for each column name.

Comment: I am trying to turn the 'id' value from three rows in table B, into the values for three columns of one row in table A.

Comment: No, that didn't work either.  It sets all three columns to the same value.